# Is there for any cover of the domain of a continuous mapping a corresponding cover of the codomain?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous mapping. Then for a cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $Y$, there is a corresponding cover $f^{-1}(\mathcal{V})=\{ f^{-1}(V)|V\in\mathcal{V} \}$ of $X$.

My question is: Is there for any cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ a corresponding cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{V})=\mathcal{U}$? If the answer is negative, which additional conditions can guarantee an affirmative answer?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you considered some simple examples, like a constant function?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. In case of a constant function only the indiscrete topology of the domain is considered.

My intuition then says that a homeomorphism guarantees an affirmative answer, but I wonder is there a weaker condition that guarantees the same?

Comment: $f$ is open and injective is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial maps, like constant ones, show that it fails in general.

if $f$ is open and bijective (no need for continuity) then take $\mathcal{V}=\{f[U]\mid U \in \mathcal{U}\}$. 1-1 gives that $f^{-1}[f[U]] = U$ for all $U$ and ontoness and openness give us that we have an open cover of $Y$.